# Deleting elements from multi Dimensional Array

Tags: java

I have a 2-dimensional array in java.

For example,

```
double count=0;
double[][] arr1 =new double[3][3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
 {
   arr1[i][j]=count;
   count++;
 }
}
```

Now, I want to remove all elements where i or j value was 1.

```
arr1[1][0], arr1[1][1], arr1[1][2], arr[0][1], arr[2][1] ...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "remove" -- java arrays are contiguous space in memory - are you looking for an `ArrayList` ?

Comment: What @C.B. said. i think it would be best if you had an ArrayList of arrays. That way you can just say matrix.remove(1); since "removing" in an array is pretty much setting the values to null, 0 or false.

Comment: You've got a typo in your inner for loop btw (i should be j)

Comment: Edited the question, Can you please have a look

Comment: Check my answer below and apply same logic to j == 1

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
 {
   if(i==1 || j==1){
     arr1[i][j]=0;
   }
 }   
}
```

or with much better efficiency :

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    arr1[i][1]=0;
}
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    arr1[1][i]=0;
}
```

Comment: By, this just value would be edited, I just want to remove ir. Edited the question, Can you please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Copies into arr2.
If you had

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]
```

You'd get

```
[1][3]
[7][9]
```

If you wanted

```
[1][-][3]
[-][-][-]
[7][-][9]
```

See shijima's answer

```
double[][] arr2 = new double[arr1.length][arr1[0].length];
int ti = 0, tj = 0;


for(int i=0; i<arr1.length - 1; i++) {
    if (i > 0)
      ti = i+1;
    else
      ti = i;
  for(int j=0; j<arr1[0].length - 1; j++) {
    if (j > 0)
      tj = j+1;
    else
      tj = j;
    arr2[i][j] = arr1[ti][tj];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` would make your life a lot easier since you could just call `remove(int)`, but if you insist on arrays you could do this.

```
double[] tmp = arr1[0];
arr1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr1, 1, arr1.length);
arr1[0] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just avoid adding anything if i = 1, that way you don't need to worry about removing anything, since it will be empty later anyway...

```
    double count = 0;
    double[][] arr1 = new double[3][3];

    outerLoop: for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                continue outerLoop;
            }
            arr1[i][j] = count;
            count++;

        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            System.out.println("arr1[" + x + "][" + y + "]=" + arr1[x][y]);
        }
    }
```